# Moving Flex MXML Application into Flash

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, flash-cs5

is it possible to move a flex mxml project into flash?

i have the project complete in mxml with actionscript but due to the fact that flex is limited in its visual animations ( no timeline! ) i would prefer to switch to using flash.

the project is relatively huge, all done in mxml and i cant just re-create it in flash, it will take months!

what do you think? is there a conversion ability or a use of flex component inside flash? if so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just enhance the current Flex application with Flash animations as needed? That way you wouldn't have to redo anything.

Comment: Agreed. Flex is just Flash, so you can create your animations using the Flash timeline and then embed it using SwfLoader.

Comment: this sounds interesting.. let me try that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no conversion utility, but as noted in the comments you can build your animation in the Flash authoring tool and import it to Flex (Flash Builder.)

The way you do this will depend on what type of animation you're trying to do.  If it's just a simple path or the animation of some type of built in shape you'll want to export the animation to FXG to easily import it into Flex.  Select the object you're trying to export and hit file->export->Export Selection.  In the export window select "Adobe FXG" as the export format.  [Try this article for more information](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WS0E26E472-1533-4297-A904-59476E8E1935.html).

If you're building an animation that needs to be controlled via scripting or is more complicated you'll need to export it as Flash content (SWF or SWC are fine.)  Then load the object in to your Flex application dynamically and script it accordingly.  Be aware that cross-swf scripting security issues may arise if you use a swf loaded at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider converting the Flex project into a Flex library project and placing the resulting swc into the class path of the Flash project.